# Is there any way to find a relation between two not related tables by foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, db-schema

I use Postgres. In this case, I have table A and table D. And between them can be multiple tables B, C and etc. How to find automatically relationships? I use [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You usually will want to set up a view (saved query) that joins your tables together A > B > C > D.  Your view can just return values from tables A and D.

if you really need to get this information dynamically, you can query postgresql's information_schema, but I'd recommend a view:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html